# depicting a partitioned circle with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can I depict the following with tikz?

[image]

With the following minimal example

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,quotes,angles}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed]  (0,0) node (v1) {} circle (4);
\draw
    (3.815,-1.2) coordinate (a) node[right] {}
    -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {}
    -- (2.52,3.1) coordinate (c) node[above right] {}
    pic["$y$", draw, <->, angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c};
\draw (b) -- (c) node [above,midway,sloped] {$x$};
\draw (a) -- (b) {};
\node [circle,fill=green] at (3.8,3) {};
\node [circle,fill=green] at (4,2) {};
\node [circle,fill=green] at (4.15,-0.5) {};
\node [triangle,fill=red] at (2.5,1.5){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

- First, "\node[triangle..." gives an error.
- Second, how can I
  remove the lower part of the circle like the picture.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible to do *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Comment: You need an arc using \draw[dashed], a couple of solid lines, another arc using \draw[->] and node[midway] {$y$}, and a bunch of \node[triangle,fill=red]{} and \node[circle,fill=green]{}.

Comment: @Andrew , I have provided a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks Hossein. Rather than posting code snippets it's better to give a full MWE that compiles, or comes close to compiling in this case. This makes it much easier for people to help, but I see that Zarko has figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows, quotes, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
TR/.style = {isosceles triangle,fill=red, node contents={}}
                    ]
\clip (-4,-2) rectangle + (9,6);
\draw[dashed]   (0,0) coordinate (c)    circle (4);
\draw           (c) to ["$x$", sloped]  ++ ( 75:4) coordinate (a)
                (c) --                  ++ (-15:4) coordinate (b)
    pic["$y$", draw, <->, angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=b--c--a};
\foreach \i in {0,15,...,60}
{
\fill[green]    (\i:4.4) circle (1mm);
\path           (\i:3) node[TR];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```